# LSTM and DENSE Error: Found array with dim 3. None expected <= 2

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to tune my hyperparameters for my algorithm and I have to use two layers: LSTM and DENSE. When I use LSTM followed by DENSE it asks me 3D input, but if I give 3D input it gives me : ValueError: Found array with dim 3. None expected <= 2.

I tried with 2 DENSE layers and 2D inputs and it works, so it definitely comes from the LTSM layer.

There it is my code :

```
def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(24, input_dim=24, activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    
    print(model.summary())
    
    return model

modelk = KerasRegressor(model=create_model, verbose = 0)

batch_size = [24,64]
epochs = [10, 50, 100]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']


param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, optimizer=optimizer)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=modelk, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, verbose = 3, error_score = 'raise')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_entrainement, Y_entrainement)

print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

X_entrainement & Y_entrainement shapes : (1416, 24, 1)

I tried to modify the output of LSTM layers with flatten(), to try different syntaxes for disclosing input's shapes etc.

I want to know how to set my LSTM parameters to fit with DENSE layers

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer! It's because you also need 2d Arrays in SearchGridCV.
Subsequently, you need to reshape it like this :

````
def create_model(dropout_rate,activation='relu'):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    #model.add(tf.keras.layers.Reshape((1416, 24,1), input_shape=(1416, 24)))
    model.add(LSTM(24, input_dim=24, return_sequences=True,activation=activation,input_shape=(24,1)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(LSTM(24, input_dim=24, activation=activation,input_shape=(24,1)))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    
    
    #print(model.summary())
    
    return model

modelk = KerasRegressor(model=create_model, verbose = 0)

batch_size = [64,32]
epochs = [100,10]
optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
dropout_rate = [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
activation = ['softmax', 'softplus', 'softsign', 'relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid', 'hard_sigmoid', 'linear']

param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, optimizer=optimizer,model__dropout_rate=dropout_rate,model__activation=activation)


grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=modelk, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, verbose = 3 ,  error_score = 'raise',scoring="r2")

grid_result = grid.fit(X_entrainement2, Y_entrainement2)

print("Best_config: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
    print("%f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))```
````